# Firebase cancel batch update after 3 seconds

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore with Swift in Xcode.

Firebase has functions named batch writes. Sometimes, the batch write, even though small, may take a second before running the completion.

Is it possible, to have a timer in the app or something, to say after like 3 seconds, cancel the batch update?

Like if there is no internet for a bit, and you don't want the batch write to wait for the internet to come back to then write it; just to cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the batch has been committed, you can no longer cancel it.

If you want to handle the case where the user is offline, you can:

- Detect whether the user is online before committing a batch.
- Use a transaction, which will immediately fail when the user is offline.
- [Clear the persistence layer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Firestore#clearpersistencecompletion:), which will cancel any pending writes and clear the cache (there's unfortunately no API call that only cancels the pending writes).